# What is the -c option for when bunzipping?

Tags: linux, compression, bzip2

I'm a bit confused with the -c flag using bunzip2.

The following line of code works well:

```
ls -l
-> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 163 Oct 25 13:06 access_logs.tar.bz2
bunzip2 -c access_logs.tar.bz2 | tar -t
```

When I would attempt to use this code without the -c flag:

```
bunzip2 access_logs.tar.bz2 | tar -t
```

I get the message:

```
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

But when showing the list `ls -l`:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10240 Oct 25 13:06 access_logs.tar
```

Documentation says:

> The left side of the pipeline is bunzip –c access_logs.tbz, which
>   decompresses the file but the (-c option) sends the output to the
>   screen. The output is redirected to tar –t.

According to the manual:

```
   -c --stdout
          Compress or decompress to standard output.
```

It seems that the decompression also works without the -c flag?

Comment: HOWTO unpack a bzip2 compressed text file : bunzip2 file.bz2

Comment: HOWTO unpack any tar archive, any suffix .gz, .xz, bz2 : tar xvf file.tar.*

Comment: »» tar: This does not look like a tar archive «« >>> Either it's no tar archive, or it's corrupt .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm confused about what you're confused about. You observed the answers to your questions, as well as read it in the documentation.

Without `-c`, `bunzip2` will decompress the `xx.gz` file and save the results as the file `xx`.  With the `-c`, it will not create a file, but rather send the result to stdout.  If you have a pipe, `|`, then instead of being printed to the terminal (which would be a mess), it becomes the input to the program on the right side of the pipe.

Comment: I was confused about the fact that -c should decompress the file according to the man page, but decompression also happens without the -c flag. Still without the -c option, the message: `This does not look like a tar archive` gets outputted to the console.

Comment: But answer given and I see now. The result needs is sent to stdout, otherwise I can't be piped to the next process.

Answer (score 0):

You cant check file information type:

```
file access_logs.tar.bz2
```

Check manual: [link](http://www.bzip.org/1.0.5/bzip2.txt)